# Weird behavior with mongoose Schema $inc operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working a todo app, it has projects and each project has `todolists`and `todoListsCount` .
When user creates a new todoList I want to increment the project's `todoListsCount`, the problem I found is that somehow after creating the first todoList the project's `todoListsCount` successfully increment but the new value is `2` I suppose to what I was expecting which is `2`  :

```
let  project= null
await Project.findOneAndUpdate( 
{_id:projectId},
{ $inc:{  todoListsCount:1 }}, 
{ new: true},
(err, doc) => {
    if (err)console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    project =doc
}
);
       

const todoList = new TodoList({
title,
owner,
projectId,
orderInProject :  project.todoListsCount,
created_at : new Date(),
progress   : 0,
done_at :  new Date(),
todos   : [],
done    : false,
})
await todoList.save()
```

as you can see in the Project schema default value of `todoListsCount` is `0`

```
import  mongoose  from 'mongoose'
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProjectSchema = new Schema(
    {
        /..rest of fields 

        todosCount  : {
            type  : Number ,
            required :false ,
            default: 0
        },
        todoListsCount     : {
            type  : Number ,
            required :false ,
            default: 0
        },
    }
)
export const Project =  mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

Comment: Check if update function is called twice , you can temporarily create an array field in schema and push any temp value whenever update function is called. The final array length in db is how many times you update function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using both await and callback for same function, can be the culprit. Try:

```
let project = await Project.findOneAndUpdate( 
{_id:projectId},
{ $inc:{  todoListsCount:1 }}, 
{ new: true}).exec();
```